# Get a the complete text in the current URL after the question mark

Tags: php

I have the followng URLs:

http://website.com/tagged?tag=egg&offset=1
http://website.com/tagged?offset=1&tag=egg

I'd like to get the following results:

```
tag=egg&offset=1
offset=1&tag=egg
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean you want to parse it from a string you can use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
$url = "http://website.com/tagged?tag=egg&offset=1";
$parsed = parse_url($url);

var_dump($parsed);

// Result
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => website.com
    [path] => /tagged
    [query] => tag=egg&offset=1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/parse_url

```
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump($_GET);`

Using $_GET, you can now use [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```
$getString = http_build_query($_GET);
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`